# What's the RedHat equivalent for Debian's apt-show-versions?

Tags: linux, package, version, rpm, apt

My question is as simple as the title of this post: is there an equivalent for RedHat like distro to the Debian's `apt-show-versions` command?

```
root@debian:~# apt-show-versions apache2
apache2/wheezy upgradeable from 2.2.22-13 to 2.2.22-13+deb7u1
```

As you can see, this command provides those fields:
    /  from  to

or, if the package is already uptodate:

```
<package_name>/<package_"released_for"> <state (uptodate)> <installed_version>
```

As I'm looking for a way to reproduce that format with a RedHat tool, I tried something like that:

```
rpm -qa --queryformat "%{NAME}/??? ??? from %{VERSION} to ???"
```

but some fields are missing to me.

Any idea to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Please try `yum` command (https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/9934).
For instance:

```
yum info <package_name>
```

will show you information about `package_name`, like available updates in the given repos (https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Configuring_Yum_and_Yum_Repositories.html)

Comment: `apt` is to `dpkg` as `yum` is to `rpm`. If you want anything more advanced than simple installation of packages, you go to `yum` the same way you would go to `apt` on a Debian-based box.